# Bash script commands not working in cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have the following bash script to read logs and check for brute force then block violating IP using iptables.

```
#!/bin/bash
#blah blah run some commands to get the IP
iptables -A INPUT -s $p -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
echo "BANNED $p FOR $COUNT ATTEMPTS" |wall
```

I did chmod 755. When I run the command from terminal it works fine. But when I setup a cronjob using `crontab -e` as root, it gets the IP and echos the "BANNED ..." message to the wall but nothing is added to the iptables list.

PS. I tried both `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/bin/sh` but no luck.

Comment: why do you need to add iptables rules in cron, if you want to add iptables rulesand you want them to be persistent you can add them to /etc/sysconfig/iptables or rc.local

Comment: You need to set your PATH properly to find `iptables`.

Comment: that would require restarting the iptables service yes?

Comment: Try adding the full path of all commands. `which iptables` will give it to you for `iptables`, do the same for the others.

Comment: done Mark! way to go! thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to provide full path to iptables e.g.

```
$ which iptables
/sbin/iptables
```

and than modify your script like that:\

```
#!/bin/bash
#blah blah run some commands to get the IP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s $p -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
echo "BANNED $p FOR $COUNT ATTEMPTS" |wall
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution should work for you:

```
cat cronjob
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Then:

```
chmod +x cronjob
chmod +x script.sh

/etc/init.d/crond start  #redhat based servers like centos
/etc/init.d/cron  start  #debian based servers like ubuntu

crontab cronjob
```

NOTE: Sometimes you need to enter full path of IPTABLES command if your rules aren't added to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` .

Comment: While this is a more general and interesting solution, I don't think it is a problem on cronjob configuration, but on the paths of the scripts.

Comment: Yes..path of script and path of iptables command maybe is the problem