# Bash Script Command Not Executing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debugging, iptables

I need help with the following Bash v4.1.2 script.

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=$1
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
$IPTABLES -I INPUT -s $IP -j DROP
echo $IPTABLES -I INPUT -s $IP -j DROP |wall
```

The variables, `IP` and `IPTABLES`, get populated in the `echo` but the line above is not executed.  The echo outputs...

`/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP`

...which is syntactically correct and works if executed manually.

I don't know Bash so I'm struggling to debug this elementary script.  I see some scenarios where commands are left bare as I have mine and some that are wrapped in `$()` (with and without quotes).  I've also tried using backticks and quoting various parts of the command.  The `echo` piped through `wall` only exists for debugging.

I found a basically identical post at [Bash script commands not working in cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984318/bash-script-commands-not-working-in-cron).  My script is not running from cron though.

=== EDIT ===
Added for @Barmar

```
[root@server tmp]# bash -x /bin/netfilter-drop.sh 
+ IP=1.2.3.4
+ IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
+ /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
+ wall
+ echo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
[root@server tmp]# 
Broadcast message from root@server (Thu Dec 29 12:46:44 2016):

/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
^C
[root@server tmp]#
```

Comment: It should work fine. What makes you think it's not executed?

Comment: The rule is not added to netfilter.  The rule is not displayed by iptables.

Comment: Make sure the file doesn't have CRLF line endings. If you edit a Unix file on Windows, use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: All Linux machines here.

Comment: Then it should work. Run the script with `bash -x scriptname` so it will show every command as it executes it.

Comment: Are you running it as root?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - good question - no, the script runs as apache.  Maybe my sudo entry is wrong??  `apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/netfilter-drop.sh`.  I guess calling the script with sudo still does not allow access to manage rules?

Comment: The `wall` makes me think you're not running this from a terminal and therefore can't see all the helpful error messages that the script produces.  Add `exec &> /tmp/mylog` to the start of the script, run it however you do it, then look at the file. If you're invoking it from as web server, @gniourf_gniourf guessed your problem

Comment: @thatotherguy and @gniourf_gniourf: Aye!  `iptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table filter: Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`.  So the problem is my sudo.  That output was revealed by @thatotherguy's `exec` suggestion.

Comment: Fixed my sudo.  Script works now.  Thanks everybody.  Somebody post up an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had initially only given sudo access to run the posted Bash script.  The problem was not the script, rather it was permissions.  I needed to give additional sudo access to run iptables in my sudoers.  Fixed.